# Merging different size datasets

Tags: python-3.x

I can't seem to properly merge two datasets of diff dimensions.

```
df1                            
1   3   4
NaN 2   2
1   1   1

df2
1  
3 
1

desired df
1   3   4
3   2   2
1   1   1
```

Comment: what have you tried and how did you try to merge?

Comment: Hopefully now it's easier to understand. I have been trying to use the left join,, with a lot of different combination but it's not working

Comment: Post your attempt as a [MCVE] so that others don't duplicate your efforts or can point out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're looking for is to fill the NaN values with the corresponding df2 value, you'll need `pandas` module and can do the following:

`df = df1.fillna(value=df2.to_dict())`

Here's a sample:

```
df1

     0  1  2
0    1  3  4
1  NaN  2  2
2    1  1  1

df2
   0
0  1
1  3
2  1

df = df1.fillna(value=df2.to_dict())

df

   0  1  2
0  1  3  4
1  3  2  2
2  1  1  1
```

If I understand correctly `df2` must have the same column names as `df1` for this to work.